# unexpected output of C++

Tags: c++, pointers, undefined-behavior, post-increment

I found unexpected output of following program.

Here pointer `ptr` point to address of variable `i` and `i` hold the value `10`. It means the value of `ptr` also `10`. Next `ptr` increment once. It means now it hold value `11`. But in the following program ptr prints `12`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *ptr = &i;
    int j = 2;
    j += *ptr++;

    cout<<"i : "<<i<<"\n";
    cout<<"j : "<<j<<"\n";
    cout<<"ptr : "<<*ptr<<"\n";
}
```

[Output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sTNtel5skjoCOrd4):

```
i : 10
j : 12
ptr : 12
```

So  I don't understand why `ptr` prints `12` instead of `11`?

Comment: Undefined behavior can do all sorts of crazy things.

Comment: Please pick a tag.  Is this C or C++?

Comment: Undefined behavior. Due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `*ptr++` is parsed as `*(ptr++)`. There must be a duplicate for this, somewhere, unless my memory is playing tricks on me..

Comment: Since you expected `11`, did you intend to use `(*ptr)++` ?

Comment: `ptr` never holds the value 10 - `*ptr` does. Print `ptr`, `&i + 1` and `&j` and compare them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior.

This statement

```
j += *ptr++;
```

is equivalent to

```
j += *( ptr++ );
```

So the pointer now points to after the variable i that is it does not point to a valid object.

Thus this statement

```
cout<<"ptr : "<<*ptr<<"\n";
```

invokes undefined behavior.

It happened such a way that the compiler placed the variable j after the variable i. However the order of the variables is unspecified by the C++ Standard.

For example the gcc compiler's output is the same as you showed.

```
i : 10
j : 12
ptr : 12
```

While the clang compiler's output is

```
i : 10
j : 12
ptr : 4201824
```

What you mean is the following

```
j += ( *ptr )++;
```

In this case the output will be

```
i : 11
j : 12
ptr : 11
```

Pay attention to that the outputted value of `i` is `11` because the variable `i` is outputted in the following sentence when the side effect was already applied to the variable.

Comment: Note for causal readers (Vlad already is aware of this):  _"So the pointer now points to after the variable i that is it does not point to a valid object."_  It is okay to have a pointer point to after the variable, but it is NOT okay (undefined behavior) to dereference that pointer.  So things like `std::all_of(ptr, ptr+1, somepredicate)` is okay on a pointer to a non-array single object.

Comment: @Eljay: Even though the Standard allows for the creation of just-past pointers, and equality comparisons between arbitrary pointers, gcc and clang are both prone to act nonsensically if a pointer to one object and a pointer just past another are compared and found to be equal.

Comment: @supercat • My understanding is that `ptr` and `ptr+1` is okay, but comparing `ptr` and `some_other_ptr+1` is not okay.  It's a very limited (but useful) case where `ptr+1` is allowed, which happens to work well with the ranged based algorithms for the single object as the `begin` and `end`.  (Bottom line:  the C++ abstract machine is not the same as one's actual computer; the optimizer can surprise in delightful ways.  Assuming one finds "long, late night debug sessions" to be delightful.) I believe that all jibes with your point.

Comment: @Eljay: The C Standard expressly allows for *equality* comparisons between arbitrary pointers, and I'm pretty sure the C++ Standard does as well.  The C Standard even goes so far as to expressly recognize the possibility of a comparison between a just-past pointer for one object and a pointer to another object, noting that such a comparison will report the pointers equal if the second object directly follows the first.